# Change series order in stacked charts

Tags: charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

When I use any of the stacking modes, suddenly series are not in their original order (values from the columns from left to right).

I have found this description on https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart :

> If set to true, stacks the elements for all series at each domain
>   value. Note: In Column, Area, and SteppedArea charts, Google Charts
>   reverses the order of legend items to better correspond with the
>   stacking of the series elements (E.g. series 0 will be the bottom-most
>   legend item). This does not apply to Bar Charts.

Which is actually not true (or maybe I am doing something wrong here), because I am really interested in stacked bars. Please check the screenshot below.

Is there any way of changing the order in stacked charts?

No stacking, series are in the correct order:

[image: No stacking, series are in correct order]

Stacked. Series are out of order/reversed order:

[image: Stacked. Series are out of order/reversed order]

Comment: what exactly is reversed? Do you mean this part? - https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TBZ7.png

Comment: sorry, didnt mark this one. Yes, I mean the part with the legend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strange, wanted to look at this question because never noticed legend being reversed before.

I realize this is the script version and not on a sheet,
but typically, both work the same.

however here,
the legend is reversed when in default position on the right, as expected.
but legend appears as desired when moved to the top.
see following working snippets...

**legend at right**

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var options = {
    isStacked: true,
    
    chartArea: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      top: 24,
      left: 32,
      right: 128,
      bottom: 32
    },
    height: 400,
    width: '100%'    
  };
  var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Series 1', 'Series 2', 'Series 3'],
    ['04/01/2019', 40, 13, 20],
    ['16/01/2019', 50, 15, 33],
    ['28/01/2019', 60, 20, 10],
    ['09/02/2019', 43, 7, 6]
  ]);
  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**legend at top**

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var options = {
    isStacked: true,
    legend: {
      alignment: 'center',
      position: 'top'
    },
    
    chartArea: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      top: 24,
      left: 32,
      right: 128,
      bottom: 32
    },
    height: 400,
    width: '100%'    
  };
  var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Series 1', 'Series 2', 'Series 3'],
    ['04/01/2019', 40, 13, 20],
    ['16/01/2019', 50, 15, 33],
    ['28/01/2019', 60, 20, 10],
    ['09/02/2019', 43, 7, 6]
  ]);
  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

note: I checked previous, older versions of google charts, all worked the same.

Comment: so the issue is with latest version of JS ? :)

Answer (score 3):

Try putting data for the in reverse order that you want? This has helped me

Comment: This worked for me too, I just changed the column order and it switched the order in which they were stacked.